# Grails / HIbernate Postgresql cannot query previously created object

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, grails

we are using Grails 4 with Hibernate 5 and Postgresql and I ran into a strange problem which I don't know how to troubleshoot.

I have created a test which creates a `Family` (a large object graph having around 20 INSERT and UPDATE queries) and then it tries to retrieve it using its id.

So there is a `FamilyController` extending `grails.rest.RestfulController`having `static responseFormats = ['json']` and the following methods:

```
    @Override
    protected Family createResource() {

        def instance = new NewFamilyCommand()

        bindData(instance, getObjectToBind())
        instance.validate()
        //Check for binding errors
        if(instance.hasErrors()) {
            throw new ValidationException('Unable to bind new family', instance.errors)
        }

        //Send the command to the service, which will return us an actual Family domain object
        return familyService.addFamilyToUser(instance)
    }
```

and

```
    @Override
    protected Family queryForResource(Serializable id) {
        def family = familyService.safeGetFamily(Long.parseLong(id))
        ...
        return family
    }
```

Running this in a loop using a Cypress test, and it works fine most of the time.

Problem is that from time to time (seems to be a multiple of `50` which coincidentally is the number of `maxConnections` configured in Tomcat) querying the `Family` by the returned id does not find it.

Here is the Tomcat configuration for the datasource (default recommended by Grails):

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    dialect: "net.kaleidos.hibernate.PostgresqlExtensionsDialect"
    username: "test"
    password: "test"
    properties:
        initialSize: 2
        maxActive: 50
        minIdle: 2
        maxIdle: 2
        maxWait: 10000
        maxAge: 10 * 60000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
        validationQuery: "SELECT 1"
        validationQueryTimeout: 3
        validationInterval: 15000
        testOnBorrow: true
        testWhileIdle: true
        testOnReturn: false
        jdbcInterceptors: "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)"
        defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
        removeAbandoned: true
        removeAbandonedTimeout: 300
```

Postgresql runs in a docker container with 2 PIDS for this database, let's say `73` and `74`.

I looked in the Postgresql logs and I noticed a difference between a successful test and a failed one.

In a successful scenario, both the Family creation and the Family retrieval run in the same PID.

In a failed scenario, the Family creation is performed by pid `74` and Family retrieval is performed by PID 73.

What is more curious is that PID 73 is idle most of the time, it runs it's first query around the creation of Family 50 (presumably when the connections are started to being reused) and then at Family 101 is getting used in the Family retrieval query, whose transaction begins **before** PID 74 Family creation transaction commits (at least that is shown in Postgres logs but maybe the logs are not printed chronologically).

Checking the database right after the test fails, I see the Family saved in the database and also the tests pass if I add a little wait time before querying for the result.

I am wondering how could that be, I assume that Postgresl return the ID only after the transaction is being committed, and then why would the other PID not see it?

Any help in troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: seems to be related to Hibernate.FLUSH_MODE. If I set `sessionFactory.currentSession.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL)` in `familyService.addFamilyToUser(instance)` the problem goes away and the statements are properly ordered. It seems that Hibernate flushes the session too early returning the family id even if Postgres does not commit all the insert/update statements.

Comment: "Running this in a loop, and it works fine most of the time." - Does that mean you have some external process that is repeatedly sending requests to the app, one to create and then one to retrieve (2 separate HTTP requests)?

Comment: Yes, it's a Cypress test

Comment: It is a little unusual that the return type of your controller actions is `Family`.  Can you show what is in your `Family create()` and `Family get(Long id)` actions?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown updated the question with code from our controller

Comment: "updated the question with code from our controller" - It looks like you removed references to controller actions that declare `Family` as a return type.  Are you using the `get` and `create` that are inherited from `RestfulController` or do you have your own implementations which have the return types that were expressed in the original question?

Comment: no, Family is still the return type, just posted the exact method names. We are using `RestfulController`

Comment: "no, Family is still the return type" - Can you show the controller actions that have the `Family` return type?

Comment: It's `protected Family createResource() ` and `protected Family queryForResource(Serializable id) `, I have added them in the question. Maybe they are not visible ?

Comment: Those are not controller actions.  Those are methods in your controller which specifically are not configured as controller actions.  I understand what you meant now.  Your original question included `Family get(Long id)` and `Family create()` which look like controller actions.  I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OK, please let me know if I should add anything else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235656/discussion-between-cip123-and-jeff-scott-brown).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was our fault, we messed around with the `DirtyCheckable#hasChanged` implementation and the code generated a lot of `UPDATE` statements after the initial insert and this caused the session to be flushed several times and the underlying Posgresql transactions were out of sync with the Hibernate transactions